# How to embed laravel blade into wordpress project?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, mariadb

I created a form in **laravel** blade with dynamic references from database, and i want to display this form into **wordpress**, is there any solution without using iframe?

I tried to do this with **iframe** successfully, but it's not recommended for **SEO**.

What do you think to use an API between Wordpress and Laravel ? It'll be helpful ?

Comment: You can either integrate the blade parser into your WordPress project, or just change the blade components of the one template to match WordPresses template parses...

Comment: My question is why you want to use Laravel in WordPress? There already good things with WordPress.

Comment: @Ice76 it's not possible since i retrieve data from database to reach dropdown list

Comment: @MayankDudakiya In our needs, we have to use wordpress as CMS and all processing we should use laravel